# pdb: step into operator of classes

Tags: python, debugging, overriding, operator-keyword, pdb

I have two python objects for which I made the classes. As part of defining the methods, I reimplemented the equality operator `__eq__`.

This implementation of the operator is somehow throwing the wrong boolean for some objects, for example:

`obj1 == obj2` throws `False`, when I was expecting it to be `True`.

I wanna debug that equality operation in pdb, however, when I use `s(tep)`, it doesn't go to the implementation of that operator, it just moves to the next instruction as if I used `n(ext)`.

Any ideas on how to debug these operators in pdb?

Comment: If these objects are implemented in C, you can't step into their `__eq__` implementation.